# Mysql Drop column where all row value is null

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i drop all columns from a table where all its values are null ?

i have a huge table (100k+ rows) with around 20+ columns, lots of these columns are not used at all, so i want to remove all columns that is NULL in all rows

Comment: `delete from table where col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null ... ` repeat for all the columns

Comment: @ajreal i dont want to delete rows, i want to drop the column it self

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through each field in a cursor and perform the check and `ALTER` in one fell swoop, or you can just run a check in one step to see which fields aren't used:

```
SELECT MAX(col1) col1
      ,MAX(col2) col2
      ,MAX(col3) col3
      .....
FROM YourTable
```

Then remove any fields that have a `MAX()` of `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP col2
```