# ALTER TABLE WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, alter-table

I am not well versed with DDL. I was under the assumption that they was a `WHERE` Clause for `ALTER` and I have understood now after some research  that `WHERE` Clause doesn't exist for `ALTER` Command. How to handle cases where we might need to check some conditions in the `ALTER` Command?

[Mysql Drop column where all row value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331778/mysql-drop-column-where-all-row-value-is-null/26331889#26331917)

For example, for the above question, If I want to write something like the code below How do I do it?

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP col
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table
                    WHERE col IS NOT NULL)
```

Is there any standard SQL way to achieve this? If not can anyone provide ways to do it for the various databases (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL)?

Comment: It needs to be done using if condition using t-SQL in case of SQL server

Comment: What type of database do you want to run this against? They will all have different syntaxes

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a answer including the various syntaxes like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql/1293347#1293347) answer

Answer (score 5):

You cannot drop a column for only certain rows in a table. The table either has the column or it doesn't. This is why there is no `WHERE` clause for `ALTER`.

It sounds like you are looking to drop this column only if all of the values are `NULL` in the table.  What you need is an `IF` statement.

Updated:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col IS NOT NULL)
        THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS my_result

IF my_result = 'Y'
    ALTER TABLE...
```

Comment: I understand why there is no `WHERE` clause for `ALTER` and that was not my question.

Comment: Can you add an example using the `IF` statement as mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for code. Can you add on which databases the code works?

Comment: The IF dont work. 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF my_result = 'Y''